# Undefined Reference in SFML

Tags: c++, g++, sfml

This is my first C++ project with libraries and I cannot figure out how to link the libraries correctly. I've gotten a hello world to work but I can't get a window to open with sfml.

I have tried to reorder the libraries in my tasks.json file, I have tried changing between static and dynamic libraries, I have reinstalled G++ and SFML multiple times. The closest I've been able to get to a compilation was a undefined reference error. Below are my project file that I have been using.

tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++11",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main.exe",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.cpp",
                "-I\"C:/SFML-2.6.1/include\"",
                "-L\"C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib\"",
                "-lopengl32",
                "-lfreetype",
                "-lsfml-graphics-s",
                "-lsfml-window-s",
                "-lsfml-system-s"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

main.cpp

```
#define SFML_STATIC
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window({ 1920u, 1080u }, "CMake SFML Project");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thank You for your patience

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete build-log. Copy-paste it as text.

Comment: You need to do something in your program, otherwise it simply ends before you have a chance to see the window. Look at one of the SFML tutorials.

Comment: You need to put opengl after sfml in the linker command

Comment: Maybe `C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib` does not contain SFML binaries that are compatible with your compiler. My advice for MinGW is to uninstall your current one and follow the [official VSCode MinGW instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) which told you to use msys2 to install MinGW. And after you did that use `pacman` (the package manager in msys2) to install the proper `SFML` binaries for your compiler: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-sfml?repo=ucrt64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-sfml?repo=ucrt64)

Comment: @AlanBirtles is correct. The order of linking is important for the linker used in g++